# Como consigo copiar conteúdo de uma div para um hiddenfield?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, div, ip

Tenho uma div que exibe o IP do usuário, na qual, esse endereço é pego por JavaScript. Porém, preciso utilizar o IP no Code-behind. A ideia seria copiar o conteúdo da div para um hiddenfield e trabalhar em cima dele. Estou tendo problema para fazer essa cópia. Segue abaixo o código:

```
<script>
 var RTCPeerConnection = /*window.RTCPeerConnection ||*/
 window.webkitRTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection;

    if (RTCPeerConnection) (function () {
    var rtc = new RTCPeerConnection({ iceServers: [] });
    if (1 || window.mozRTCPeerConnection) {
        rtc.createDataChannel('', { reliable: false });
    };
    rtc.onicecandidate = function (evt) {
        if (evt.candidate)
            grepSDP("a=" + evt.candidate.candidate);
    };
    rtc.createOffer(function (offerDesc) {
        grepSDP(offerDesc.sdp);
        rtc.setLocalDescription(offerDesc);
    }, function (e) { console.warn("offer failed", e); });


    var addrs = Object.create(null);
    addrs["0.0.0.0"] = false;
    function updateDisplay(newAddr) {
        if (newAddr in addrs) return;
        else addrs[newAddr] = true;
        var displayAddrs = Object.keys(addrs).filter(function 
    (k) { return addrs[k]; });
     document.getElementById('list').textContent =
     displayAddrs.join(" or perhaps ") || "n/a";
    }

    function grepSDP(sdp) {
        var hosts = [];
        sdp.split('\r\n').forEach(function (line) {
            if (~line.indexOf("a=candidate")) {
                var parts = line.split(' '),
                    addr = parts[4],
                    type = parts[7];
                if (type === 'host') updateDisplay(addr);
            } else if (~line.indexOf("c=")) {
                var parts = line.split(' '),
                    addr = parts[2];
                updateDisplay(addr);
            }
        });
    }
   })();
    else {
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = "<code>ifconfig| grep inet | 
    grep -v inet6 | cut -d\" \" -f2 | tail -n1</code>";
    document.getElementById('list').nextSibling.textContent = "In Chrome and 
  Firefox your IP should display automatically, by the power of 
   WebRTCskull.";
 }

   $('#btn').on('submit', function () {
    var valor = $('#list').val();
    $('#HiddenField1').val(valor);
   });
 </script>

 <div id="list"></div>
  <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Seu código está sujo, com implementações que não se aplicam a pergunta. Mas vou tentar te ajudar.

Para obter o conteúdo do hiddenField basta:

```
var conteudo = document.getElementById("HiddenField1").value;
```

já para gravar conteúdo no hiddendField basta:

```
document.getElementById("HiddenField1").value = "192.168.0.1";
```

Answer (score 2):

Me parece que você está tentando pegar um *value* de uma div:

```
<div id="list"></div>          <-- a "div"
var valor = $('#list').val();  <-- pegando o "valor"
```

A div não possui "value". Se você quer pegar o **texto** da div, use `.text()`:

```
$("#list").text().trim();
```

O `.trim()` remove possíveis espaços gerados pelo HTML.

Outra coisa é que você está jogando o conteúdo da div no campo ao fazer o submit. Seria melhor colocar um `setTimeout` para garantir que dê tempo do campo receber o valor antes do submit:

```
$('#btn').on('submit', function (e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var $this = $(this);
   var valor = $('#list').val();
   $('#HiddenField1').val(valor);
   setTimeout(function(){
      $this.submit();
   }, 50);
});
```

O `e.preventDefault();` impede que o formulário seja submetido no evento, e o `$this.submit();` no `setTimeout` irá fazer o envio após uma fração de segundo após o texto da div ter sido colocada no campo `#HiddenField1`.

Agora, o que se nota é que você está fazendo um submit de um botão `#btn` (pelo nome do id parace que seja um botão, e não o formulário). Se esse id se refere ao botão que submete o formulário, está errado. Esse id deveria ser o id do formulário, algo como:

```
<form id="form" ...>

   // elementos do formulário

   <button id="btn">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

E no código seria o id do form e não do botão:

```
$('#form').on('submit', function (e){
      ↑
```

Ou seja, esse id `#btn` não é nem necessário ter, se for esse o caso.

Answer (score 1):

Para pegar o html de qualquer div com jquery utilize o seguinte argumento

```
var valorDiv = $('#list').html();
$('#id_input').val(valorDiv);
```

Comment: Olá amigo. Eu já havia tentado dessa maneira mas não funcionou, o campo hiddenfield vem vazio.

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse link https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield?view=netframework-4.8 ele tem uma função de change do valor do hiddenfield